# Functional style java.util.regex match/group extraction

Tags: java, regex, java-9

Using java.util.regex to extract substrings I find myself implementing the same code pattern working around calls to :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern); // can be static final
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) { // or m.matches()
    foo(m.group(x));
} else {
    ...
}
```

Is there a functional extension or popular library (guava / apache commons) that avoids the ugly unnecessary and error-prone local variable, like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern); // can be static final
p.matchedGroup(input, x) // return Optional<String>
    .map(group -> foo(group))
    .orElse(...);
```

and also a stream of match results like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
p.findMatches(input)
    .map((MatchResult mr) -> {
        mr.groupsIfPresent(x).map(g -> foo(g)).orElse(...)
    })
    .findFirst();
```

It seems the only functional addition in Java8 was `.splitAsStream()` but that only helps when trying to split around matches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The following is only available from [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9)**

You're probably looking for `Matcher::results` which produces a `Stream<MatchResult>`

You can use it in the following way for example

```
p.matcher(input)
 .results()
 .map(MatchResult::group)
 .findAny()
 .orElse(null);
```

An addition added by **Holger** and which is intersting would be, while reading a `File` and looking for a pattern to directly use `Scanner::findAll` to avoid loading the whole file in memory using `File::lines`

Comment: ah, Java9+ only. I was still on Java8

Comment: also nicer if you can start the code with variable p, like `p.matcher(input).results()...`

Comment: It’s also worth noting the addition of `Scanner.findAll​(Pattern)`, as too often, people start with `Files.lines()` instead, to search the line strings then, e.g. with `flatMap`, instead of streaming over the matches in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

There is an elegant solution that works for both `Stream<String>` and `Optional<String>`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("...");

List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> matches = input.stream()
        .map(pattern::matcher)
        .filter(Matcher::find)
        .map(m -> m.group(x))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Though I would like to point out that doing a modifying/mutating operation in a `filter`-call is unusual. Please be careful when you do mutating operations in `filter`calls and avoid them as much as possible. For this case it's fine though (from my subjective viewpoint) as you modify an object you just created in your stream that isn't used outside of the stream operations.

Use `Optional.ofNullable/of` when you only have one input, everything else looks the same.

Comment: Would also be nice to mention how to call find() multiple times to cover all occurences. Probably also easier with Java9 takeWhile

Comment: upvoting because it works for java8, but accepting java9 answer as the future way of doing this.

Comment: What actually is x in that example?

Comment: Check the JavaDoc of `Pattern` or `Matcher`: `group(0)` is the whole match, `group(1)` is the the first matched parenthesis pair in your pattern.